# React HOC callback not working with default props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components, recompose

I made a simple HOC with recompose but for some reason its not working with default props. if I provide the props from outside its working properly, but not with the default props (I get 'onCallback' is not a function, so basically an undefined error)

My HOC:

```
import React from 'react'

import { withStateHandlers, withHandlers, compose } from 'recompose'

const editableRow = () =>
    compose(
        withStateHandlers(
            { isEditing: false, editingId: null },
            {
                toggleEditing: ({ isEditing, editingId }) => entryId => ({
                    isEditing: !isEditing,
                    editingId: isEditing ? null : entryId
                })
            }
        ),
        withHandlers({
            handleSave: ({
                isEditing,
                editingId,
                onEdit,
                onCreate,
                list
            }) => values => { return onEdit(25) }
        })
    )

export default editableRow
```

Where I trying to use it with default props AND its not working:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Checkbox, Icon, Table, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import editableRow from 'hoc/editableRow'

const DataRow = (props) => 
    <Table.Row 
        onClick={props.handleSave}>
        {
            props.children
        }
    </Table.Row>

DataRow.defaultProps = {
    onCreate: value => console.log('100'),
    onEdit: value => console.log(value * 2)
}

export default editableRow()(DataRow)
```

Where I provide its props, so its working properly:

```
<DataRow
    onCreate={(value)=>console.log('on create', value*2)}
    onEdit={(value)=>console.log('onEdit', value*3)}
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its cause of the order you add this to the component. So you need `onCreate` inside of the HOC but the default props are added to component, in this case they never passes the HOC. But if you add them from outside the HOC can access them:

```
     ┌──────────────────────────────┐     
     │        {onChange: fn}        │     
     └─────────────┬────────────────┘     
                   │                      
                   │                      
                   │                      
                   │                      
┌──────────────────▼─────────────────────┐
│                                        │
│                 HOC                    │
│                                        │
│                                        │
│        ┌──────────────────────┐        │
│        │       DataRow        │        │
│        │                      │        │
│        │   defaultProps: {    │        │
│        │      onChange: fn    │        │
│        │   }                  │        │
│        └──────────────────────┘        │
└────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Ah man, makes sense, I thought it was something like this. Thanks! :)